# Deactivate toggle function if an <a> gets clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, toggle

Here is my code:

```js
var workshops = document.querySelector('#workshops');
var cross_one = document.querySelector('#cross_one');
var workshops_navigation = document.querySelector('#workshops_navigation');
workshops.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (cross_one.style.display == "") {
          cross_one.style.display = "none";
        workshops_navigation.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          cross_one.style.display = "";
          workshops_navigation.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );



var works = document.querySelector('#works');
var cross_two = document.querySelector('#cross_two');
var works_navigation = document.querySelector('#works_navigation');
works.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (cross_two.style.display == "") {
          cross_two.style.display = "none";
        works_navigation.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          cross_two.style.display = "";
          works_navigation.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );



var projects = document.querySelector('#projects');
var cross_three = document.querySelector('#cross_three');
var projects_navigation = document.querySelector('#projects_navigation');
projects.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (cross_three.style.display == "") {
          cross_three.style.display = "none";
        projects_navigation.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          cross_three.style.display = "";
          projects_navigation.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );
```

```css
#workshops {
  left: 4vw;
  top: 32vh;
  position: absolute;
}

#works {
  right: 10vw;
  top: 5vh;
  position: absolute;
}

#projects {
  right: 5vw;
  top: 20vh;
  position: absolute;
}

#workshops_icon, #works_icon, #projects_icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 354px;
}

#workshops_navigation, #works_navigation, #projects_navigation {
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  line-height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="workshops">
<div id="workshops_icon">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 235.1 299.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 235.1 299.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="white" points="0.8,298.5 234.3,298.5 234.3,0.8 0.8,0.8 0.8,298.5 "/>
<polygon id="cross_one"  points="233.6,299.1 117.6,151 1.5,299.1 0.2,298 116.5,149.7 0.2,1.3 1.5,0.3 117.6,148.3 233.6,0.3 
 234.9,1.3 118.6,149.7 234.9,298 "/>
<path d="M235.1,299.4v-1.7V1.7V0h-1.7H1.7H0v1.7v296v1.7h1.7h231.8H235.1L235.1,299.4z M233.5,297.7H1.7V1.7h231.8
 V297.7L233.5,297.7z"/>
</svg>
<div id="workshops_navigation">
<a href="#">Workshops</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="works">
<div id="works_icon" class="svg_color_change icon">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 235.1 299.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 235.1 299.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="white" points="0.8,298.5 234.3,298.5 234.3,0.8 0.8,0.8 0.8,298.5 "/>
<polygon id="cross_two"  points="233.6,299.1 117.6,151 1.5,299.1 0.2,298 116.5,149.7 0.2,1.3 1.5,0.3 117.6,148.3 233.6,0.3 
 234.9,1.3 118.6,149.7 234.9,298 "/>
<path class="st1" d="M235.1,299.4v-1.7V1.7V0h-1.7H1.7H0v1.7v296v1.7h1.7h231.8H235.1L235.1,299.4z M233.5,297.7H1.7V1.7h231.8
 V297.7L233.5,297.7z"/>
</svg>
<div id="works_navigation">
<a class="linky" href="#">Works</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="projects">
<div id="projects_icon" class="svg_color_change icon">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 235.1 299.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 235.1 299.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="white" points="0.8,298.5 234.3,298.5 234.3,0.8 0.8,0.8 0.8,298.5 "/>
<polygon id="cross_three"  points="233.6,299.1 117.6,151 1.5,299.1 0.2,298 116.5,149.7 0.2,1.3 1.5,0.3 117.6,148.3 233.6,0.3 
 234.9,1.3 118.6,149.7 234.9,298 "/>
<path d="M235.1,299.4v-1.7V1.7V0h-1.7H1.7H0v1.7v296v1.7h1.7h231.8H235.1L235.1,299.4z M233.5,297.7H1.7V1.7h231.8
 V297.7L233.5,297.7z"/>
</svg>
<div id="projects_navigation">
<a href="#">Link A</a><br>
<a href="#">Link B</a><br>
<a href="#">Link C</a><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Currently, there is a toggle function, if an icon gets clicked. That works fine. But: If a link gets clicked, it should not toggle for this action.

Sorry for the weird code.

It would be so great if someone could post here a solution! I would really appreciate it.

Thaaaaanks! Wish you all a very nice day!

Comment: Create a real event bindings (`addEventListener` or `on()`) on the link, that sets the flag to false, and stops the propagation of the event.  Then create a real event binding on whatever div is important, that on click flips the flag back.  That way the click event on children that bubble up to it (which will not be from the link due to the stopPropagation) will re-enable the toggle.  A great starting point for learning about event handling with jQuery is to browse the [Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/) site

Comment: @Taplar Thank you. I have to do it with JavaScript. And don't understand it. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/hd1c493a/1/

HTML:

```
    <div id="works">
  <div id="works_icon">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 235.1 299.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 235.1 299.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="white" points="0.8,298.5 234.3,298.5 234.3,0.8 0.8,0.8 0.8,298.5 "/>
<polygon id="cross_one"  points="233.6,299.1 117.6,151 1.5,299.1 0.2,298 116.5,149.7 0.2,1.3 1.5,0.3 117.6,148.3 233.6,0.3 
    234.9,1.3 118.6,149.7 234.9,298 "/>
<path d="M235.1,299.4v-1.7V1.7V0h-1.7H1.7H0v1.7v296v1.7h1.7h231.8H235.1L235.1,299.4z M233.5,297.7H1.7V1.7h231.8
    V297.7L233.5,297.7z"/>
</svg>

    <div id="works_navigation">
      <a href="#" class='link'> My Link 1 </a><br/>
      <a href="#" class='link'> My Link 2 </a><br/>
      <a href="#" class='link'> My Link 3 </a><br/>

    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
  var works = document.querySelector('#works');
var cross_one = document.querySelector('#cross_one');
var works_navigation = document.querySelector('#works_navigation');
works.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (cross_one.style.display == "") {
          cross_one.style.display = "none";
        works_navigation.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          cross_one.style.display = "";
          works_navigation.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  );
document.querySelectorAll('.link').forEach(function(link) { 
  link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
})
})
;
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks very good. But I have more than one graphic with several links. If I use '.link' instead of '#link', it does not work. Why?

Comment: if you want to use class instead then you have to use this method 
document.querySelectorAll instead of document.querySelector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: forexample: 

var highlightedItems = userList.querySelectorAll(".highlighted");

highlightedItems.forEach(function(userItem) {
  deleteUser(userItem);
});

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your answer? If it works, I can check and upvote it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Check now, it will work on the class rather than the id